# How is the derangement formula applicable here?

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

If $4$ letters are posted to $6$ different addresses, how many ways are there for each letter to reach wrong addresses? Or, if $6$ letters are posted for $4$ different addresses, how many ways are there for each letter to reach wrong addresses?

Note: If derangements aren't applicable here, what will be the answers of these two questions?

Comment: I don't see any derangement at all here, as it seems that more than one letter can arrive at the same destination. Also, as a practical concern, how would you post 4 letters for 6 addresses?

Comment: It's not at all applicable since a derangement is a bijection $f$ from $\{1,...,n\}$ to itself where $f(k) \ne k \;\; \forall k$. Maybe the underlying concepts, e.g. inclusion-exclusion, could be applied though.

Comment: Consider two envelopes are extra which are fake addresses..

Comment: In a derangement, the letters' addresses are _dependent_ (because if letter $A$ got address $B$, then no other letter can get address $B$).  In your question, are the letters' addresses _dependent_?  If independent, the answer is trivial.  If dependent, you gotta more fully describe what happens with the letters and envelops.